# sort a file based on length of the column/row

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, awk, sort

I need to sort a file based on the number of chars in the first column.

I have no idea on how to go about this. (On Linux, so sed/awk/sort is available).

An example:

```
.abs is bla bla 12
.abc is bla se 23 bla
.fe is bla bla bla
.jpg is pic extension
.se is for swedish domains
```

what I want is to sort these lines, based on the length of the first column in each line.
Some of the lines start with 4 characters, some start with 3, or 2. I want the result to be something like:

```
.fe is bla bla bla
.se is for swedish domains
.abs is bla bla 12
.abc is bla se 23 bla
.jpg is pic extension
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can first add another column with count of characters with `awk`, do `sort` and then strip added column:

`awk '{printf "%d %s\n", length($1), $0}' file.txt | sort -n -k1,1 | sed -E -e 's/^[0-9]+ //'`

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5917762/5419599) on Stack Overflow.  You don't need `printf` or `sed` in there, actually.

Answer (score 0):

[You can do it with basic shell tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63299/sort-a-file-based-on-length-of-the-column-row/63301#63301), but if Perl is available, you can express your requirement more directly:

```
perl -l -e 'print sort {@a = split(/ /, $a, 2); @b = split(/ /, $b, 2);
                        length($a[0]) <=> length($b[0])} <>'
```

With the [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform#The_Perl_idiom) (more efficient for large input):

```
perl -l -e 'print map {$_->[0]}
                  sort {length($a->[1]) cmp length($b->[1])}
                  map {[$_, split(/ /, $_, 2)]} <>'
```

If you have Python, the code is more verbose but a bit clearer:

```
python -c 'import sys;
lines = sys.stdin.readlines();
lines.sort(key=lambda line: len(line.split()[0]));
sys.stdout.writelines(lines)'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -vOFS='\t' '{ print length($1), $0 }' file.in | sort -k1,1n -k2,2 | cut -f2-
.fe is bla bla bla
.se is for swedish domains
.abc is bla se 23 bla
.abs is bla bla 12
.jpg is pic extension
```

This sorts the file `file.in` by the length of the data in the first column, then lexicographically on the actual data of the first column (this was not specifically requested in the question, but provides a nice touch to the result).

The `awk` code will create tab-delimited output like

```
4       .abs is bla bla 12
4       .abc is bla se 23 bla
3       .fe is bla bla bla
4       .jpg is pic extension
3       .se is for swedish domains
```

and this is what `sort` sorts, on the first column (numerically) and then the second column (lexicographically).  The `cut` then removes the first column from this.